# Powershell - Query firewall list of servers export to csv

Tags: powershell-2.0, firewall, export-to-csv, comobject

I'm using the following to query the firewall rules of a list of servers.

```
$servers = Get-Content fw_servers.txt

foreach($serv in $servers) {
$fw = New-Object -ComObject hnetcfg.fwpolicy2 

$fw.rules | 

Where-Object { $_.enabled -and $_.LocalPorts -like 3389 } | 

Select-Object -Property direction,protocol, localports,name 
}
```

I would like to export this information to a csv file. Can someone please let me know how I can use Export-CSV for this? I've tried making it into an array but it's not working for me. I'm using 2.0

I'd also like the exported data to look like the following

```
Server    Direction   Protocol   LocalPorts    Name
testsrv1  1           6          3389          Remote Desktop (TCP-In)
testsrv2  1           6          3389          Research Remote Desktop Policy
```

Thank you for your help.

Amelia

Answer (score 1):

I had an epiphany and somehow figured it out. The following, although not pretty, works for me.

```
$servers = Import-CSV fw_servers.csv
$servers | Foreach {
$serv = $_.serv
foreach-object { 
       $name = $_."Server"
       $fw = New-Object -ComObject hnetcfg.fwpolicy2 
       $fw.rules | 
       Where-Object { $_.enabled -and $_.LocalPorts -like 3389 } | 

       Select-Object @{Name="Server"; Expression={$name}}, direction, protocol, localports, name 
               }
} | Export-CSV C:\Users\trankaa\desktop\fw_res.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force
```